# Loading single image in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-imageview

I want to load image on my layout that comes from `web services`.

But every time I failed to get image from web service.

Please provide the code when web services are like that:-

```
    {
        "data": {
            "Success": "1",
            "Message": "Successful",
            "userid": "145",
            "username": "rahul",
            "password": "*****",
            "firstname": "jaydeep",
            "lastname": "darji",
            "mobile": "232312221",
            "email": "jaydeepdajri65@yahoo.in",
            "countryid": "1",
            "countryname": "India",
            "userphoto": "http:\/\/www.sevenstarinfotech.com\/projects\/demo\/okaz\/uploads\/profile\/1681692778Mar2120131938_145.png"
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't Expose your password

Comment: What's your problem exactly? JSON Parsing, displaying image from URL or something else?

Comment: using json parsing  displaying image from url

Answer (score 0):

```
http:\/\/www.sevenstarinfotech.com\/projects\/demo\/okaz\/uploads\/profile\/1681692778Mar2120131938_145.png
```

This is the URL of the image. You should parse out this URL, and then download the image and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Parse json like below:

```
try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            userphoto = data.getString("userphoto");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

for download image use below method. call it : `getBitmapFromURL(userphoto);` it give you `bitmap` use that in imageview. like :  `imagev.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: from where i have to call this getBitmapFromUrl method ,either from main class or after  userphoto = data.getString("userphoto");

Comment: I did this part try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            userphoto = data.getString("userphoto");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                                                       but where i have to implement this bitmap method . i am not having much knowledge about bitmap....so plz help me.....

Comment: i did the same thing that you told me ,but still it shows httpEngine.connect error...........

Comment: yes ,I add internet in manifest and data is coming from web service but not showing in layout

Comment: i took 1 textview to show the url of userphoto                       String urlName=jdata.getString(key_userphoto);                                  txturl.setText(urlName);                                 String image = jdata.getString(key_userphoto);     getBitmapFromURL(urlName);

Comment: by this way i call getBitmapFromURl(urlName) from onpost method

Comment: insted of book refer some tutorials which available on net. i ll saggest you:http://www.coreservlets.com/android-tutorial/ and http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html more prefarable : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: and after learnning Basic you can check this:http://dj-android.blogspot.in/ because there advance android example are available...